# How to trigger PHP/jQuery when a button is clicked

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following form:

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
<div id="edit-box">
<INPUT type="submit" name="save-text" id="save-text" value="Save">
<textarea id="editor" name="editor">
<?php echo $content; ?>
</textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if ($_POST["save-text"]){
    // get form data and do stuff here
}
```

How can I make sure that the PHP script is run only when the submit button is clicked and no other time?

Comment: Anything wrong with your current code?

Comment: yep..it doesn't do anything. I want to trigger the php based on the button id inside the form. can you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Just fill in the `action` with your php path and done. `action="path/filename.php"`

Comment: Probably want to make use of `isset()` when you check if the form has been submitted `if (isset($_POST['save-text'])) {`. Also try debugging it by throwing in an `echo 'submitted';` inside your if statement to check that it's being submitted.

Comment: @user21472 What worked for you? filling in the `action` or using the `isset()` ? Let us know so one of us can write it in as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: sorry....here's what worked for me: if(isset($_POST['save-text'])){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `if($_POST["save-text"])` returns false and so your code isn't being executed. You will need to wrap the `$_POST["save-text"]` with the `isset()` function. [isset()](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) can be used to check the existence of a certain variable and returns `TRUE` if a variable exists and has a value other than `NULL` or `FALSE`.

The correct code would look like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['save-text'])) {
    //Do something
}
```

You should also make sure your submit buttons have a 'value' attribute.  If they don't, there wont be a value in the $_POST array and so isset($_POST["submit"]) would return false.

Example:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">

isset($_POST["submit"])   // returns false

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

isset($_POST["submit"])   // returns true.
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this before the HTML tag at the start of the page.
Also don't forget to change the page name extension from `.html` to `.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['save-text'])) {
    // get form data and do stuff here
}
```